# how to generate a PDF in your HTML code  (javascript: jspdf, downloadify??)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I looked around and came up on http://code.google.com/p/jspdf

This is exactly what I need for a web app I am creating in jquery mobile, where users will be filling out a form from an iPad or whatnot (mobile), and be able to save as a PDF and I am able to pass in some variable that is a format of all the form fields, to make it look pretty and presentable as a document PDF that can be signed.

Now I was having problems with my phone testing jspdf, and apparently there is a workaround they provide and some people use saying to use jsPdf with downloadify. heres a link.

https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/wiki/Jspdf-using-downloadify

however when I use that link, it seems like I can only save it as a .txt  ... am I missing something? How can i save it as a PDF? Just changing filename.txt to filename.pdf doesnt work because it says 'file type is not supported.' how is this using jspdf at all, it seems like it is only using downloadify and sending whatever contents to a TXT, not a pdf... anyone idea on how to successfully create a PDF using this method (with downloadify) because it seems using downloadify I can actually download the file to my mobile device. Without the downloadify method, no download is done.

Comment: Anyone? I'm kinda desperate, I'm writing a jquery mobile app, a form I want to be able to save it as a PDF that I get to format out of the variables... Like a signable document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up not being able to do a clientside version, since I couldnt save the PDFs on the ipad. I ended up doing a serverside with PHP / FPDF.

Answer (score 7):

You can embed the document in the HTML.  Use js library at http://jspdf.com and the following code to embed a PDF on mobile devices, where #preview-pane is an iframe in your html.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Example PDF');
var string = doc.output('datauristring');
$('#preview-pane').attr('src', string);
```